# How to enable a checkbox using AUI script

Tags: yui, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

This is the code to get the value of a checkbox

```
         var email = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>email").attr('checked');
```

What is the code to set/enable the checkbox with a tick ?

```
         A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>email").prop('checked', email); //this does not work
         A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>email").set('value', email);//this also does not work
```

Many thanks

Comment: Does `A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>email").attr('checked', true);` work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Node#set`](https://clarle.github.io/yui3/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_set):

```
A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>email").set('checked', true);
```

Or you can use [`Node#setAttribute`](https://clarle.github.io/yui3/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_setAttribute):

```
A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>email").setAttribute('checked', true);
```